# Howto prevent service down repeated email sent alerts via bash

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a simple bash script scheduled to run every 10 minutes, which checks for the PID of any service, and if it is not found, it sends an email alert:

```
#!/bin/bash
if pgrep "mysql" > /dev/null
then
    echo "MYSQL Running"
else
    echo "ALERT Stopped"
    # Sends Email Alert blah blah
fi
```

The issue is that if somehow the required service is down permanently, it keeps sending emails every 10 minutes. How can I set up a check so that if  the service is down and an email sent once, then no emails should be sent until the service comes up again. Then, if the service is subsequently down again, a new email should be sent.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if pgrep "mysql" > /dev/null
then
    echo "MYSQL Running"
    rm -f /var/run/.mysql_mail_sent
else
    echo "ALERT Stopped"
    if [ ! -f /var/run/.mysql_mail_sent ]; then
        // send your mail here
        date > /var/run/.mysql_mail_sent
    fi
fi
```

Comment: I don't like that it's storing a dotfile in root. This might be more sensible somewhere in /var/run perhaps? Also, just having looked through that again, I think you might slightly have the wrong end of the stick - we want to remove the file when mysql starts running again, and put the file in place when it's stopped, not the other way around?

Comment: It's just an example. You can store such file in /var/run, /tmp etc.

Comment: You are free to put the file wherever you want. It is just a proposal. For my scripts I use a special directory for logfiles and these kind of dot files (but I call them with a .lck extension). Also you can create this file in the `else` part and change the startup of mysql to remove the file if you want.

Comment: I want to send email ONLY if the service is down and the email should be sent once only (until the service gets up)
Seeing your script, I can see its sending email in both conditions? can you please explain a bit?

Comment: It was only an example of bash language elements required to write your desired logic, not the finished script - because I wasn't sure about its exact behaviour you want to achieve.

Comment: can you give some working example please?

Comment: I corrected the script. Check, if that's the desired behaviour.

Comment: It's now running exactly as desired. Many thanks

Comment: I have just started to learn bash. How can I integrate this facility to following?
https://aacable.wordpress.com/2015/07/24/rough-notes-on-sending-email-alert-upon-services-failure-in-linux/

It's a long script with lots of junk, but it's just my beginning :) So I will improve hopefully.
The basic idea of this script is to check two services like mysql and radiusd. If found one or both services stopped it will start them and again check the service status and add them in file, then this file be emailed to admin. Now I want to prevent repeated email on service permanent failure.

Comment: checking for single service is fine, but how can I integrate this facility for both services? or nay better idea?

Comment: Multiple IF-s in bash work just like in any other language, eg.:  if [ "$pid1" == "" ] || [ "$pid2" == "" ]; then  ... fi   (as you can see, you can use && and || operators).

Comment: Ok just for test i have duplicated entries and its working fine for both services, if one stop it send alert for one, and if both services stopped, it sends alert for both.

But what If I want send alert for UP also? means if services goes down, it should send one email alert only, and when the service gets UP ti should send me UP email one time only?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26190/discussion-between-syed-jahanzaib-and-tomasz-klim).